# Cumulative Cost Mapping- All values are zero

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, geemap

I am trying to calculate cumulative cost of my own area. Here is the script:

```
import ee
import geemap
ee.Initialize()

Map = geemap.Map(center=[41, 29], zoom=9)

dataset_jpr = ee.FeatureCollection('users/cemrealdogan1/ist_bound')
Map.addLayer(dataset_jpr, {}, "ist_bound")

sources = ee.Image().toByte().paint(dataset_jpr, 1)

sources = sources.updateMask(sources)

cover = ee.Image('ESA/GLOBCOVER_L4_200901_200912_V2_3').select(0)
Palette = [
  '30123b', '4454c3', '448ffe', '20c7df', '2aefa1','7dff56', 'ff0000', 'f1cb3a', 'fe9029', 'ea4e0d', 'be2102', '7a0403'
]
cost = \
  cover.eq(60).Or(cover.eq(80)).Or(cover.eq(110)).Or(cover.eq(140)) \
      .multiply(1).add(
  cover.eq(40).Or(cover.eq(90)).Or(cover.eq(120)).Or(cover.eq(130)) \
    .Or(cover.eq(170)) \
      .multiply(2).add(
  cover.eq(50).Or(cover.eq(70)).Or(cover.eq(150)).Or(cover.eq(160)) \
      .multiply(3)))

cumulativeCost = cost.cumulativeCost(**{
  'source': sources,
  'maxDistance': 5 * 1000 # 5 kilometers
})

Map.addLayer(cover, {}, 'Globcover')
Map.addLayer(cumulativeCost, {'min': 0, 'max': 5e4, 'palette':Palette},'accumulated cost')
```

Map
[image]

I use geemap library Python API. My problem here is my cumulative cost values are all zero which made me suspicious about it. How can I revise the code?

Comment: By only including an image of your code, you're requiring anyone who wants to test a solution to retype all your code (which isn't likely). We have requirement here that coding Questions contain code. Please [Edit] the Question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will edit my question right away.